# How can i retrieve the value from JSON

Tags: php, json

I am trying to retrieve the discount_percentage value via PHP

```
{"status":"OK","data":[{"code":"8989898","status":null,"test_type":"General","discount_percentage":100}],"error":0}
```

This is our current code

```
$arr = json_decode($response, true);
// Access values from the associative array
 $status= $arr["status"];

 $discount_percentage="$arr";
 $toppings = json_decode($arr->data["discount_percentage"]);
```

Any help would be appreciated as currently it does not return a result

Comment: try `$arr->data[0]["discount_percentage"]`

Comment: Not necessary `json_decode`, just `$toppings = $arr->data[0]["discount_percentage"]`

Comment: This does not seems to return a result

Comment: Sorry, I realized again it's impportant to **think before doing** :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply do this :

```
$arr['data'][0]['discount_percentage']
```

your first **json_decode** is decoding all json data, even children in your array.

Comment: This is correct, as the OP is using `true` on the `json_decode`, which turns it into an associative array, *not an object*.

Comment: What's the difference with my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68652115/how-can-i-retrieve-the-value-from-json?noredirect=1#comment121326817_68652115), OP says it's wrong  :(

Comment: @codingmonster The difference is in how `json_decode` returns the output. Either as an object, or as an associative array. You simply gave the object access without saying to drop the `true` as well. Elaboration on an answer helps make a clear point. :) https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Try `$toppings = $arr->data[0]["discount_percentage"]`.